# Prevent application from accepting telerik RadGridView column as drag/drop data

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik, radgridview

Currently i have the problem with Telerik `RadGridView` and drag/drop columns for grouping. At this moment we are switching from WPF `DataGrid` to Telerik `RadGridView` which allowes columns to be draged and dropped for grouping. But also our application accept files to be dragged and dropped into the application.  The problem is, that if i use the grid for grouping data via Drag&Drop, the application think, that i try to drag/drop a file.

The question: How can i detect, whether the dragged and dropped item is a telerik RadGridView column?

Is some thing like this a good idea:

```
string[] formats = e.Data.GetFormats();
if (!formats.Contains("DraggedCell"))
{
    // Process file drag and drop
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the way dealing with dropped data. I switched from a blacklist system to a whitelist system, so i proof whether the content is acceptable or not. I do not exclude things any more.